# Prevent Background Image from automatically resizing after adding elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have a desktop parallax effect on my background image for my website (the image is set to cover).  Unfortunately, I am unable to replicate parallax on mobile so the background image "jumps" (e.g. resizes) every time an additional element is added (e.g. adding an extra row).  Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

you can try css attribute `background-attachment: fixed;` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp